# Width in print style sheet working for printing for first time only

Tags: html, css

I have the following NoPrint.css print style sheet:

```
    /* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}          

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    margin: 0px;

}

.header
{
    display:none;
}

.header h1
{
    display:none;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;  
}


div.chart
{
    clear:both;
    float:left; 
    width:45%;
}

/*
 --- Suitable when the print orientation is landscape*/

div.chart4
{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.DatumSetzen
{
    float:left;
    width:45%; 
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
div.vorwocheChart
{
    clear:both;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
div.chartV
{
    clear:both;
    float:left; 
    width:45%; 
}
div.chart4V
{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}
div.Labels
{   
    display:none;
}    
.drucken
{
    display:none;   
}
```

Markup for the page layout:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link href="~/Styles/NoPrint.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> </head> <body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>                    
                    AVIS
                    <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server"><%=DateTime.Now.Year%></asp:Label> <!-- Displays current year in the main heading of the website-->
         &nbsp;</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <asp:LinkButton ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" onclick="HeadLogin_Click">Anmelden</asp:LinkButton> ]

                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>                        
                        Willkommen <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!                        
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Abmelden" LogoutPageUrl="~/Logout.aspx"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal"  >

                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Wiegen.aspx" Text="WIEGEN"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Granulieren.aspx" Text="GRANULIEREN" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Sieben.aspx" Text="SIEBEN" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Verkapseln.aspx" Text="VERKAPSELN" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Tablettieren.aspx" Text="TABLETTIEREN" />

                   </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">   
        <div class="button">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" DefaultButton="BT2" runat="server">

             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/printButton.png" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" ToolTip="Drucken"/>  
                    <asp:Button ID="BT2" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" EnableTheming="False" Enabled="False" Visible="False" />

            </asp:Panel>               
            </div>     

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

This is applied to a webpage having three charts, two on left side and one on right side, and the print style sheet work fine for the first time when print command is given, the three charts are printed on one sheet with landscape orientation as expected, but for the second time, it prints one chart per page, float is working but the width is not being picked up. I am using Internet Explorer for my application. I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest what is wrong with it.

Comment: please show us the markup you use for the page layout

Comment: I updated the question, is this you asked for ?